# I'm trying to fetch data from 3 apis but I can't. The first api returns data successfully but I can't input that into the 2nd api

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I'm building a web app using Node, Express, Cors and Body Parser. The app uses the fetch api to fetch data from online apis. Now I have written all the code with a server.js file, an index.html and an app.js. My server.js file contains the express server functions and middleware. My app.js contains the main functionality. Here are my files:

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Weather Journal</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="holder headline">
      Weather Journal App
    </div>
    <form id="userInfo">
      <div class="holder zip">
        <label for="zip">Enter City here</label>
        <input type="text" id="city" placeholder="enter city here" required>
      </div>
      <div class="holder feel">
        <label for="date">Enter departure date</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" id="date" required>
        <button id="submitBtn" type="submit"> Generate </button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="holder entry">
      <div class="title">Most Recent Entry</div>
      <div id="entryHolder">
        <div id="lat"></div>
        <div id="lng"></div>
        <div id="countryName"></div>
        <div id="temp"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

My app.js:

```
const geoURL = "http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?";
const geoUsername = `rohanasif1990`;
const weatherURL = "https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily?"
const weatherKey = "20028a8267a24bba9a807362767bc4a7"

let d = new Date();
let newDate = d.getMonth() + 1 + "." + d.getDate() + "." + d.getFullYear();


const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const city = document.getElementById("city").value;

    if (city !== "") {
        getCity(geoURL, city, geoUsername)
            .then(function (data) {
                getWeather(weatherURL, weatherKey, data["geonames"][0]['lat'], data["geonames"][0]['lng'])
            }).then(weatherData => {
                postWeatherData("/addWeather", { temp: weatherData })
            }).then(function () {
                receiveWeatherData()
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                alert("Invalid city");
            })
    }
})

const getCity = async (geoURL, city, geoUsername) => {
    const res = await fetch(`${geoURL}q=${city}&username=${geoUsername}`);
    try {
        const cityData = await res.json();
        return cityData;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
    }
}


const postWeatherData = async (url = "", data = {}) => {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: "same-origin",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            temp: data.temp
        })
    });

    try {
        const newData = await response.json();
        return newData;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

const receiveWeatherData = async () => {
    const request = await fetch("/allWeather");
    try {
        const allData = await request.json()
        document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = allData.temp;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error)
    }
}

const getWeather = async (weatherURL, weatherKey, lat, lon) => {
    const res = await fetch(`${weatherURL}&lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&key=${weatherKey}`);
    try {
        const weatherData = await res.json();
        return weatherData;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
    }
}
```

My server.js:

```
// Setup empty JS object to act as endpoint for all routes
cityData = {};
weatherData = {};
picturesData = {};

// Require Express to run server and routes
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

// Start up an instance of app
const app = express();

/* Middleware*/
//Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Cors for cross origin allowance
app.use(cors())
// Initialize the main project folder
app.use(express.static('website'));

app.get("/all", function sendData(req, res) {
    res.send(cityData);
})

app.get("/allWeather", function sendWeather(req, res) {
    res.send(weatherData);
})

app.get("allPictures", function sendPictures(req, res) {
    res.send(picturesData);
})

app.post("/add", (req, res) => {
    projectData['lat'] = req.body.lat;
    projectData['lng'] = req.body.lng;
    projectData['countryName'] = req.body.countryName
    res.send(cityData);
})

app.post("/addWeather", (req, res) => {
    weatherData['temp'] = req.body.temp;
    res.send(weatherData);
})

app.post("/addPicture", (req, res) => {
    picturesData['pic'] = req.body.pic;
    res.send(picturesData);
})

// Setup Server
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("App listening on port 3000")
    console.log("Go to http://localhost:3000")
})
```

I am trying to get the geonames api to fetch the latitude and longitude of a city . Then I want to use the latitude and longitude to fetch the weather for that location. The pictures api is not implemented yet. I just want to use the data fetched from one api (geonames.org) as input to the other api (weatherbit.io). Right the app returns undefined when I console.log the final data.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: I get no errors. Can you create the files at your end and run "node server.js" to see what you get?

Comment: Something may be wrong in `getCity` or `getWeather`. The fetch is outside the try/catch so it's unreachable for catching erros. I tried the `getCity` function with the fetch inside the try/catch and It logs the error `Failed to fetch`.

Comment: right now I console.logged weatherData and it is undefined. I don't know how to fix that. weatherData should contain the json data fetched from the api but it doesn't

Comment: Add `app.use(express.json())` after declaring your `app` and `res.json(object)` instead of `res.send()` for all your routes in your server file.

Comment: That doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking the Promise then chain. You do not return any promise so that it can be chained. Pasting modified example withe capital `RETURN`
statements

```js
        getCity(geoURL, city, geoUsername)
            .then(function (data) {
                RETURN getWeather(weatherURL, weatherKey, data["geonames"][0]['lat'], data["geonames"][0]['lng'])
            }).then(weatherData => {
                RETURN postWeatherData("/addWeather", { temp: weatherData })
            }).then(function () {
                RETURN receiveWeatherData()
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                alert("Invalid city");
            })
```

A better would be to write the function as Async, I see you have done that already

So

```js
submitBtn.addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const city = document.getElementById("city").value;

    if (city !== "") {
      try {
        const city = await getCity(geoURL, city, geoUsername);
        const weatherData = await getWeather(weatherURL, weatherKey, city["geonames"][0]['lat'], city["geonames"][0]['lng']);
     
         //and so on
      } catch (e) {
         console.log(error);
         alert("Invalid city");
      }

    }
})
```

Comment: thanks for this... although it improves the code but doesn't get me the required result of getting the temperature on the html page

Comment: `getCity(geoURL, city, geoUsername)
            .then(function (data) {
                return getWeather(weatherURL, weatherKey, data["geonames"][0]['lat'], data["geonames"][0]['lng'])
            }).then(weatherData => {
                console.log(weatherData['data'][0]['temp'])
                return postWeatherData("/addWeather", { temp: weatherData['data'][0]['temp'] })
            }).then(function () {
                return receiveWeatherData()
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                alert("Invalid city");
            })`

Comment: adding this console.log here gets the temperature to log on the console but I can't pass it onto the next function which is postWeatherData

Answer (score 0):

The problem was here:

```
const receiveWeatherData = async () => {
    const request = await fetch("/allWeather");
    try {
        const allData = await request.json()
        document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = allData['temp'];
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error)
    }
}
```

I replaced allData['data'] with allData['temp']